# How to remove blank lines in a quick way (regex?)

Tags: php, regex

an external program generates a file for me like this:

```
"lorem ipsum",

"lorem ipsum",
"lorem ipsum",

"lorem ipsum"
```

and I want to obtain:

```
"lorem ipsum",
"lorem ipsum",
"lorem ipsum",
"lorem ipsum"
```

I would like to remove these free spaces made by creating a new line, I was thinking about regex but I have no idea how to do it.

I tried regex but didn't find query

Comment: `preg_replace("/\n{2,}/", "\n", $string)` will replace 2+ newlines with a single newline.

Comment: "I have no idea how to do it" is a little too easy. The least you can do is read the [php documentation about regular expressions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.introduction.php) and look at the available [Pearl-Compatible-Regular-Expressions functions in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php). The PHP documentation is excellent and always has examples as well. There is no shame in posting an honest attempt.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP function `preg_replace` is used for replacing by regex. Actual regex is based matching multiple consecutive new line (`\n`) by single one.

```
<?php
$str = '"lorem ipsum",

"lorem ipsum",
"lorem ipsum",

"lorem ipsum"
';

echo("<pre>" . preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", $str) . "</pre>");
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer, but this code return me this: https://pastebin.com/raw/QLkpFtCT and i want me to return this https://pastebin.com/2ufNm2aS

Comment: @Misaz: Note that there's no information about the newline sequence (or sequences) used in the original string, that can be `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n` or something more exotic like a vertical tab or the NEL character. So read about the `\R` alias and the way to set it. Also, your actual answer do not remove the trailing newlines (nor eventual leading newlines). To finish, what if one of these "blank lines" contains a space? I know it is hard, but life is hard.